# PHP make drop down and grab data

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Okay so I've been struggling with a problem I have to solve for class and I feel like I've made myself lost. I'm trying to take the choice from a drop down list and display a registered notification with the info displayed. Everything I've found hasn't been a fix and everytime my code gets sloppier. here is what I'm trying.

```
 <form action="login_manager.php" method="post">

    <label>Customer: </label>
    <?php echo $customer['firstName'] . " " . $customer['lastName'];?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Product: </label>
    <select id="productkey" name="productkey">
        <?php foreach($products as $product) :
            $name = $product['productName'];
            $productID = $product['productCode'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>">
                <?php echo $name; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <?php 
    $selected = $_POST['productkey']; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register">
       
        <input type="submit" value="Register Product">
        <br>
</form>
```

login manager

```
else if ($action == 'register') {
$selected = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'productCode');
$product = select_product($selected);
include('registered_product.php');
```

}

```
function select_product($product) {
global $db;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products
    WHERE productName = :product';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':product', $product);

$statement->execute();
$productID = $statement->fetch();
$statement->closeCursor();
return $productID;
```

}

registered product
page just has this

```
<?php echo "product ". $product . " was registered." ?>
```

I've tried product['productCode'] and the likes and can't get it to display anything. I'm at a loss and I'm lost in my code at this point with the various things I've tried. Any point in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: I like the php delusions website, which demonstrates that when using pdo, the bindValue() step can be skipped. (Confusingly, it also uses `[ ]` instead of `array()`, where I think the former is a deprecated method)

Comment: Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & always try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)